# / and - in different cells after same function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to concatenate a column of dates and other of hours.

The fuction:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(AGENDA!B9 ,"dd-mm-yyyy"), " ", TEXT(AGENDA!C9 ,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

works, but, some cells are in fuction format, dd-mm-yyyy, and some others are dd/mm/yyyy (the time is correct). I need them all with -

[image: 1]

Comment: Include you sheet link, please

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1270Yp4NHzQ8g8PjF30Mvnb9yphZmKnuB/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118318008899193506757&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: make access for everyone with a link

Comment: done sorry. it should be good now

Comment: No its not take a look at [this](https://youtu.be/CNN967bemQg?t=359), a recreated it already. just includ it for othe respondants

Comment: it should be good https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13M2yMAMUivuHBc83AjajUNRKSxHSAODUqS23_2Sx7SE/edit?usp=sharing, I already gave permission to ppl with link in editor mode

Comment: no share it View only to prevent visitor from tampring with it unless its a dummy sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have a non valid date in AGENDA sheet Fecha column note `Luque, Hugo 20/08/2021`
 with month set to 20 !! and day is 08.

[image: date]

> To add date validation, Select `B2:B` and go to Data data > validation > Criteria: date.

and select On invalid data: Show warning.
Fix the date **one by one** or take a look at the **quick fix**.

To check the date format:

> Go to Formst > number > Custom date and time.

[image]

**The Quick fix**

To get date fixed with a formula from, `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd-mm-yyyy` you need a helper column lets call it **Fixed Date**, with the formula.

```
=IF(ISDATE(B2)=False,CONCATENATE(INDEX(SPLIT(B2,"/-"),1,2),"-",INDEX(SPLIT(B2,"/-"),1,1),"-",INDEX(SPLIT(B2,"/-"),1,3)),B2)
```

[image]

**Explanation**

1 - [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)([`ISDATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381?hl=en)`(B2)=False` check the date is valid if true return the original value example `B2` if false calculate the formula.

2 - [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)`(`[`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)`(B2,"/-"),1,2)` to get the month column that resulted from [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) function with column set to `2`.

3 - [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)`(`[`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)`(B2,"/-"),1,1)` to get the day column that resulted from [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function with column set to `1`.

4 - [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)`(`[`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)`(B2,"/-"),1,3))` to get the yaer column that resulted from [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function with column set to `3`.

5 - [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) the columns with `"-"` in between.

> Now you can paste your formula but adjusted in BBDD.AGENDA Sheet `B3` cell.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,TEXT(AGENDA!C2 ,"dd-mm-yyyy"),TEXT(AGENDA!D2 ,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

Notice that we changed `AGENDA!B2` with `AGENDA!C2`.

[image]